# Where is my SqLite Database - which is embedded within AIR application and installed in Windows 7?

Tags: apache-flex, windows-7, air, adobe

Where is my SqLite Database - which is embedded within AIR application and installed in Windows 7?

Dear All,

I have a Flex AIR application with SQLite database embeded in it. 
But that does not store data within the database.db file stored in C:\Program Files(86)[Program Name]\assets.

The application is running and saving data/ displaying them perfectly fine.

What is the issue? Where is the database location in windows 7

I have heared something called App_Data in win 7 - is it some where within it? if else, where is that folder?

Help Help.

Thanks
Sumit

Thanks
Sumit

Answer (score 5):

C:\Users[Username]\AppData\Roaming[ApplicationName].[SomeCharacters] I think

Answer (score 2):

The path provided by Florian F would be correct for a flash application, but not so for an installed AIR application.

According to the [ASDocs](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/filesystem/File.html), the following are *commonly used directory locations* when writing files:

- File.applicationStorageDirectory—a storage directory unique to each
  installed AIR application
- File.applicationDirectory—the read-only directory where the
  application is installed (along with any installed assets)
- File.desktopDirectory—the user's desktop directory
- File.documentsDirectory—the user's documents directory
- File.userDirectory—the user directory

This does not mean that the application is locked down to writing to these locations, but they are a good place to look.